# Change route on Modal Open - React

Tags: reactjs, routes, react-router, modal-dialog

Is there a way to change the route on opening a modal in React using react-router-dom.

I made the modal using react-modal and its meant to display an image up close, so I want to update the route with the image ID, so that I can send a get request to my server using the ID in req.params.id and fetch the image and other related data.

Also on modal close, I would like to be redirected back to the gallery route.

Any help would be much appreciated, have a lovely weekend!

Comment: Do you already have the images loaded in the gallery component?

Comment: yes, sir! I am just trying to change the route to the current pic ID when I click on the modal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can. 
For example you have gallery page (**/gallery**) with a lot of images and then you click to some image. It must be wrapped by link like this:

```js
<Link to={'/gallery/${image.id}`}>
  <img src={image.src} alt={image.alt} />
</Link>
```

In the end of the gallery component you need to add next code

```js
<Route
  path="/gallery/:id"
  children={({ match }) => {
    return (
      <Modal onClose={onClose} isOpened={Boolean(match)}>
        <ImageModalContent id={match && match.params.id} />
      </Modal>
    );
  }}
/>
```

The main trick is use property children. See the documentation

> Sometimes you need to render whether the path matches the location or
>   not. In these cases, you can use the function children prop. It works
>   exactly like render except that it gets called whether there is a
>   match or not.
>   Blockquote

If the path works for current url, match is object which includes id of image and if the path doesn't work for current path, match is null. It is enough for you case

And inside **ImageModalContent** on **componentDidMount** you can load any data what you want

You can find more details in this video

EN: https://youtu.be/RYo3kwdDdBI
RU: https://youtu.be/4YHnZSMo9vo

Comment: this is working, Can you tell me that, if I want to display the signup modal from anywhere on the app, how can I do that? I tried with this, but it changes the page entirely

Answer (score 0):

You could do a method that uses a redirection on the click function, and then check in a useEffect and push it to the url let me explain it:

```
const [ redirect, setRedirect ] = useState(null)

useEffect(() => {
    history.push(redirect)
}, [ redirect ];


<Button onClick={() => setRedirect(image.id)}>
    Image here
</Button>
```

Might have some errors but do you get the idea?